# Using styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a button which need to be styled using styled component. As I am new to react I need your help in getting button color change to green on success and blue on failure. Also I have class card-preview which need to have box shadow when I hover on it while using styled component .The below code will give you an idea what I am trying to do.

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  background: ${(props) => (props.success ? "green" : "blue")};
  color: white;
`;

const Cardlist = ({ cards, title }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card-list">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <div className="card-preview" key={card.id}>
          <h2>{card.name}</h2>
          if({card.status}==='success')
          <Button success>{card.status}</Button>
          else
          <Button pending>{card.status}</Button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Cardlist;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the button and CSS I think what you have *should* be working, though it could be more DRY. The `if-else` isn't valid in JSX anyway. I'm also not sure what you do with the `pending` prop, but it appears to be the antithesis of the `success` "state".

```
const Button = styled.button`
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  background: ${(props) => (props.success ? "green" : "blue")};
  color: white;
`;

...

{cards.map((card) => (
  <div className="card-preview" key={card.id}>
    <h2>{card.name}</h2>
    <Button
      success={card.status === 'success'}
      pending={card.status !== 'success'} // <-- may not be necessary
    >
      {card.status}
    </Button>
  </div>
))}
```

To apply some style to the `card-preview` div you just need to convert that to a styled-component as well.

```
const CardPreview = styled.div.attrs(() => ({
  className: "card-preview",
}))`
  :hover { // <-- sometimes you need &:hover to get the parent node
    // apply box-shadow and any other CSS rules here
  }
`;
```

Then replace the div with `CardPreview` component.

```
{cards.map((card) => (
  <CardPreview key={card.id}>
    <h2>{card.name}</h2>
    <Button success={card.status === 'success'} >
      {card.status}
    </Button>
  </CardPreview>
))}
```

See [Pseudoselectors & Nesting](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting)

Update: Reagarding [.attrs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs)

> This is a chainable method that attaches some props to a styled
> component.

It simply allows you to specify prop values when the component is created versus when it's being used. The `className` prop looks to be a static "card-preview" so may as well set it once and forget it (*in this specific case*).

Comment: I have class card-preview which need to have box shadow when I hover on it while using styled component .How to do that?

Comment: @Beginner Ah, I was in the process of addressing your additional question/requirement. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: could you explain this function styled.div.attrs(()

Comment: @Beginner Sure thing, again, please see update to answer.